# Lists forced into 2 columns - IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've been doing a page with two separate lists, though I want them underneath each other, instead of going into 2 different columns as it does in IE7.

How can I change the css to force the list in the 2nd columns to go in below in IE 7?

```
        <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>

}
#howitworks .getmore_info ul{
    float:left;
    margin-top:0;
}
#howitworks .getmore_info ul li{
    padding:3px 0;
    list-style:inside;
}
```

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float:left from the ul and it should work fine.

Comment: Put the below code in your stylesheet and then use ul class="nofloat" whenever you need unordered lists underneath each other
`.nofloat {
clear:both
}`

Comment: If this does not work, there's probably some inheritance problem going on. This [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/PzRqp/) in IE7 (or IE9, and run tools with F12).

Comment: Yeh i'm not sure, its fine in all other browsers, the problem is only with IE 7.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by applying an inline style to the first ul element - width: 100%, this forces the other ul element to a new line.